# Чем заменить метод $emit, который раньше был в socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Пример: *otherModule.js*

```
exports.post = function (req, res, next) {
  var sid = req.session.id;
  var io = req.app.get('io'); 

  req.session.destroy(function (err) {
    io.sockets.$emit('session:reload', sid);
    // ...
    res.redirect('/');
  }
};
```

Обработчик в *socket.js*

```
io.sockets.on('session:reload', function(sid) {
  // ...
});
```

Необходимо просто сгенерировать событие из другого модуля, для дальнейшей обработки.